# Python - Database for small scale static data

Tags: python, database

Been studying Python on my own for some months. I'm about to ventur into the field of databases. I am currently aiming to create a very small scale application which would feature retrieving data based on a simple search (keyword) and reflect static data linked to it. Some numbers to put it in perspective:

- About 150-200 "key" values
- About 5-10 values to be displayed per "key" value
- Editable (although the info tends to remain same most of time - maybe 1 or 2 amendments/month in total on all data stored)

An example would be the cards you see when you do a simple google search. For example you search for an actor (key value) and your query generates a "card" with values (age, length, wage, brothers,...).

As it would be the first attempt on creating something which works with such a (for me personally) larger amount of data, I am a bit puzzled with the options available to me. I have been reading up on different database models (relational,..). Ultimately I came to below 3 possibilities:

- XML
- database
- hardcode

I intend on making the data amendable by 1 privileged user. This alone makes hardcoding it not really an option. Even though, as I am a novice, I could be interpreting this wrong here.

I'd be happy if you could point me in the right direction and if you'd go for a database, which one you'd recommend going for (MySQL,..).

Many thanks in advance. If I made any error with the post (as it is my initial post), do not hesitate to point this out.

Comment: See the documentation [Data Persistence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html) particularly [**`pickle`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [**`sqlite3`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: Thanks! I am looking into sqlite3 and it's doing exactly what I wanted so far.